# Winforms: system.windows.forms.label text displayed as text in label

Tags: c#, winforms, text, label

I have created a simple program. One of the functions is that it counts clicks, and when the program finishes, a label is displayed with some text and the number of clicks. The code works, but the problem is that the label displays extra text, like this:
[system.windows.forms.label text](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NmK3e.png)

Stevec is set to count clicks. Lable konec already contains text, and in this case I just want to add the extra sentence with the number of clicks.

`konec.Text = konec + " Kliknil si: " + Stevec.ToString() + "-krat!";`

If anyone has any idea how to display only the text that I have set in the code, I would appreciate it!

Comment: When you see the type name back then you can safely assume that you accidentally used the ToString() method.  Which is exactly what the compiler had to do to turn `konec` into a string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need the **Text** property instead of the control itself:

```
konec.Text = konec.Text + " Kliknil si: " + Stevec.ToString() + "-krat!";
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason that you have unwanted text is because of this part:

```
...konec +...
```

`+` operator used with string implicitly converts other operand to string calling its `ToString()` method. This way, above part is equivalent to `...konec.ToString() + ...` (which results in unwanted text), but what you want is `...konec.Text + ...`, that is why your code should use `konec.Text` instead of just `konec` object.