# How to fix "System.Windows.Forms.Label, Text:" appearing in result?

Tags: c#

I'm attempting to put on click listeners on various labels on a form in the program I'm creating. When clicked, the event handler passes a string value into a function that creates the desired string, and adds it to the wanted textbox. But it prefixes every string addition with "System.Windows.Forms.Label, Text: ".

I've attempted to use the solution as suggested here, which is to have the textbox text be appended in the manner of textbox.text = textbox.text + resultString. [Winforms: system.windows.forms.label text displayed as text in label](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49716416/winforms-system-windows-forms-label-text-displayed-as-text-in-label)

An example of one of the onclick listeners is

```cs
private void AthleticsLabel_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            strengthRolling("Athletics");
        }
```

and an example of one of the functions it calls is

```cs
public void strengthRolling(string value)
        {
            int rollResult = myCharacter.rollStr(20);
            int secondRoll = myCharacter.rollStr(20);
            int result;
            if (myCharacter.checkProf(value))
            {
                rollResult += myCharacter.Proficiency;
                secondRoll += myCharacter.Proficiency;
            }
            if (AdvantageButton.Checked == true || DisadvantageButton.Checked == true)
            {
                if (AdvantageButton.Checked) { result = Math.Max(rollResult, secondRoll); }
                else { result = Math.Min(rollResult, secondRoll); }
            }
            else { result = rollResult; }
            ChatDisplayBox.Text += Environment.NewLine + charName + " rolled a " + result.ToString() + " on their " +value+ " check.";
        }
```

If clicking on the Athletics label, I hoped to have a message as follows be added to the ChatDisplayBox:
Mlarcin rolled a 15 on their Athletics check.

However the result currently is:
System.Windows.Forms.Label, Text: Mlarcin rolled a 15 on their Athletics check.

Comment: So `charName` is a TextBox, right? Try `charName.Text`. You want the text *from* the control, not the whole control. As a rule, when something isn't what you expect, your first move is always to find out what you've actually got there.

Comment: Thank you, I realized that I'd only made that addition to one of the functions that handle the labels, and not all of them. Once added they're all working as expected!